# How to make something appear on an HTML webpage when Javascript variables are 'correct'?

Tags: javascript, html, button

If anyone is familiar with A Dark Room I'm trying to make a system like that. If I have 10 wood and 10 leaves, then a Build Tent button would appear. I can make the button invisible, but I can't make it reappear when wood>=10 and leaves>=10. Here's the snippets that I can't get to work;

function to get the tent button to appear in JS

```
function seeTent() {
if(wood >= 10 && leaves >= 10) {
    document.getElementById('tentHide').style.display='block'; return false;
}
```

HTML counterpart

```
<button style="display: none"; id="tentHide"; onClick="buildTent()">Build Tent</button>
```

I'm just not sure if there's an event I can give it to do this after browsing through them so I'm stuck. I appreciate any help given, thanks!

Edit: Here's the full .js file

```
var wood = 0;
var rocks = 0;
var leaves = 0;

function collectWood(number) {
    wood = wood +  number
    document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
};

function collectRocks(number) {
    rocks = rocks +  number
    document.getElementById("rocks").innerHTML = rocks;
};

function collectLeaves(number) {
    leaves = leaves +  number
    document.getElementById("leaves").innerHTML = leaves;
};

function seeTent() {
    if(wood >= 10 && leaves >= 10) {
    document.getElementById('tentHide').style.display='block'; return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: where are you calling `seeTent`? Are the  `wood` and `leaves` variables accessible from `seeTent`

Comment: I just edited in the full .js file, and it lookes like the variables should be accessible. Also I put seeTent there as a placeholder because I don't how to implement the function into the html to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want something to happen depending on what values `wood` and `leaves` contain, you need to call `seeTent` any time they do change. You can do this by explicitly calling `seeTent()` in both the functions that increment your `wood` and `leaves` variables.

```
function collectWood(number) {
    wood = wood +  number
    document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
    seeTent();
};

function collectLeaves(number) {
    leaves = leaves +  number
    document.getElementById("leaves").innerHTML = leaves;
    seeTent();
};
```

If you are able to change your data around you could use [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to "watch" for when the data changes and trigger your function when the conditions are met

```
var data = {
    wood:0,
    leaves:0
};

var dataProxy = new Proxy(data,{
   set: function(target,propname,value){
      target[propname] = value;
      window.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent("dataupdate") );
   }
});

window.addEventListener("dataupdate",seeTent);

function collectWood(number) {
    dataProxy.wood = dataProxy.wood +  number;
    document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = dataProxy.wood;
};
```

Demo using Proxy/CustomEvent

```js
var data ={
  wood: 0,
  rocks: 0,
  leaves: 0
},
woodBtn = document.getElementById("woodbtn"),
rocksBtn = document.getElementById("rocksbtn"),
leavesBtn = document.getElementById("leavesbtn"),
tentBtn = document.getElementById("tentbtn"),
woodEle = document.getElementById("wood"),
rocksEle = document.getElementById("rocks"),
leavesEle = document.getElementById("leaves");
    

var dataProxy = new Proxy(data,{
  set: function(target,propname,value){
    target[propname]=value;
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("dataupdate"));
  }
});

window.addEventListener("dataupdate",seeTent);
woodBtn.addEventListener("click",collectWood);
rocksBtn.addEventListener("click",collectRocks);
leavesBtn.addEventListener("click",collectLeaves);



function collectWood(number) {
    dataProxy.wood = dataProxy.wood + 1;
    wood.innerHTML = dataProxy.wood;
};

function collectRocks(number) {
    dataProxy.rocks = dataProxy.rocks + 1;
    rocks.innerHTML = dataProxy.rocks;
};

function collectLeaves(number) {
    dataProxy.leaves = dataProxy.leaves +  1;
    leaves.innerHTML = dataProxy.leaves;
};

function seeTent() {
  if(dataProxy.wood >= 10 && dataProxy.leaves >= 10) {
    tentBtn.classList.remove("hidden");
    return false;
  }
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
#legend {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  font-size:12px;
  width:120px;
  padding:5px;
}
#controls {
  display:flex;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="legend">
  <div>Wood <span id="wood"></span></div>
  <div>Rocks <span id="rocks"></span></div>
  <div>Leaves <span id="leaves"></span></div>
</div>
<div id="controls">
  <button id="woodbtn">Collect Wood</button>
  <button id="rocksbtn">Collect Rocks</button>
  <button id="leavesbtn">Collect Leaves</button>
  <button class="hidden" id="tentbtn">Build Tent</button>
</div>
```